# "Dynamic figures"

Tags: math-software

Which kind of software allows to do things like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aCardioid_construction.gif) or [that one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPendulum_170deg.gif), for example?

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical Software such as Mathematica can.

Comment: I've got Mathematica but I'm not able to do things like that. Do you suggest any website where I can learn?

Comment: ...http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/